# Why do the functions in my javascript controller only work individually, but not if both are in the same file?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

Here is my code:

```
    ({
        doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
            var action = component.get("c.getCampaigns");
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var name = response.getState();
                if (name === "SUCCESS") {
                    var objCampaign = response.getReturnValue();
                    component.set("v.campaigns", response.getReturnValue());

                    // CALENDAR CODE STARTS
                    var Calendar = function(model, options, date) {
                        // Default Values
                        this.Options = {
                            Color: '',
                            LinkColor: '',
                            NavShow: true,
                            NavVertical: false,
                            NavLocation: '',
                            DateTimeShow: true,
                            DateTimeFormat: 'mmm, yyyy',
                            DatetimeLocation: '',
                            EventClick: '',
                            EventTargetWholeDay: false,
                            DisabledDays: [],
                            ModelChange: model
                        };
                        // Overwriting default values
                        for (var key in options) {
                            this.Options[key] = typeof options[key] == 'string' ? options[key].toLowerCase() : options[key];
                        }

                        model ? this.Model = model : this.Model = {};
                        this.Today = new Date();

                        this.Selected = this.Today
                        this.Today.Month = this.Today.getMonth();
                        this.Today.Year = this.Today.getFullYear();
                        if (date) {
                            this.Selected = date
                        }
                        this.Selected.Month = this.Selected.getMonth();
                        this.Selected.Year = this.Selected.getFullYear();

                        this.Selected.Days = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDate();
                        this.Selected.FirstDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month), 1).getDay();
                        this.Selected.LastDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDay();

                        this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month - 1), 1);
                        if (this.Selected.Month == 0) {
                            this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year - 1, 11, 1);
                        }
                        this.Prev.Days = new Date(this.Prev.getFullYear(), (this.Prev.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();
                    };

                    function createCalendar(calendar, element, adjuster) {
                        if (typeof adjuster !== 'undefined') {
                            var newDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month + adjuster, 1);
                            calendar = new Calendar(calendar.Model, calendar.Options, newDate);
                            element.innerHTML = '';
                        } else {
                            for (var key in calendar.Options) {
                                typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'function' && typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'object' && calendar.Options[key] ? element.className += " " + key + "-" + calendar.Options[key] : 0;
                            }
                        }
                        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

                        function AddSidebar() {
                            var sidebar = document.createElement('div');
                            sidebar.className += 'cld-sidebar';

                            var monthList = document.createElement('ul');
                            monthList.className += 'cld-monthList';

                            for (var i = 0; i < months.length - 3; i++) {
                                var x = document.createElement('li');
                                x.className += 'cld-month';
                                var n = i - (4 - calendar.Selected.Month);
                                // Account for overflowing month values
                                if (n < 0) {
                                    n += 12;
                                } else if (n > 11) {
                                    n -= 12;
                                }
                                // Add Appropriate Class
                                if (i == 0) {
                                    x.className += ' cld-rwd cld-nav';
                                    x.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                        typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
                                        createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
                                    });
                                    x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,75 100,75 50,0"></polyline></svg>';
                                } else if (i == months.length - 4) {
                                    x.className += ' cld-fwd cld-nav';
                                    x.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                        typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
                                        createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
                                    });
                                    x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 100,0 50,75"></polyline></svg>';
                                } else {
                                    if (i < 4) {
                                        x.className += ' cld-pre';
                                    } else if (i > 4) {
                                        x.className += ' cld-post';
                                    } else {
                                        x.className += ' cld-curr';
                                    }

                                    (function() {
                                        var adj = (i - 4);

                                        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                            typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
                                            createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);
                                        });
                                        x.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:' + (1 - Math.abs(adj) / 4));
                                        x.innerHTML += months[n].substr(0, 3);
                                    }()); // immediate invocation

                                    if (n == 0) {
                                        var y = document.createElement('li');
                                        y.className += 'cld-year';
                                        if (i < 5) {
                                            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year;
                                        } else {
                                            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year + 1;
                                        }
                                        monthList.appendChild(y);
                                    }
                                }
                                monthList.appendChild(x);
                            }
                            sidebar.appendChild(monthList);
                            if (calendar.Options.NavLocation) {
                                document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).innerHTML = "";
                                document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).appendChild(sidebar);
                            } else {
                                element.appendChild(sidebar);
                            }
                        }

                        var mainSection = document.createElement('div');
                        mainSection.className += "cld-main";

                        function AddDateTime() {
                            var datetime = document.createElement('div');
                            datetime.className += "cld-datetime";
                            if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
                                var rwd = document.createElement('div');
                                rwd.className += " cld-rwd cld-nav";
                                rwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                    createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
                                });
                                rwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,50 75,0 75,100"></polyline></svg>';
                                datetime.appendChild(rwd);
                            }
                            var today = document.createElement('div');
                            today.className += ' today';
                            today.innerHTML = months[calendar.Selected.Month] + ", " + calendar.Selected.Year;
                            datetime.appendChild(today);
                            if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
                                var fwd = document.createElement('div');
                                fwd.className += " cld-fwd cld-nav";
                                fwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                    createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
                                });
                                fwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 75,50 0,100"></polyline></svg>';
                                datetime.appendChild(fwd);
                            }
                            if (calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation) {
                                document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).innerHTML = "";
                                document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).appendChild(datetime);
                            } else {
                                mainSection.appendChild(datetime);
                            }
                        }

                        function AddLabels() {
                            var labels = document.createElement('ul');
                            labels.className = 'cld-labels';
                            var labelsList = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
                            for (var i = 0; i < labelsList.length; i++) {
                                var label = document.createElement('li');
                                label.className += "cld-label";
                                label.innerHTML = labelsList[i];
                                labels.appendChild(label);
                            }
                            mainSection.appendChild(labels);
                        }

                        function AddDays() {
                            // Create Number Element
                            function DayNumber(n) {
                                var number = document.createElement('p');
                                number.className += "cld-number";
                                number.innerHTML += n;
                                return number;
                            }
                            var days = document.createElement('ul');
                            days.className += "cld-days";
                            // Previous Month's Days
                            for (var i = 0; i < (calendar.Selected.FirstDay); i++) {
                                var day = document.createElement('li');
                                day.className += "cld-day prevMonth";
                                //Disabled Days
                                var d = i % 7;
                                for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
                                    if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
                                        day.className += " disableDay";
                                    }
                                }

                                var number = DayNumber((calendar.Prev.Days - calendar.Selected.FirstDay) + (i + 1));
                                day.appendChild(number);
                                days.appendChild(day);
                            }
                            // Current Month's Days
                            for (var i = 0; i < calendar.Selected.Days; i++) {
                                var day = document.createElement('li');
                                day.className += "cld-day currMonth";
                                //Disabled Days
                                var d = (i + calendar.Selected.FirstDay) % 7;
                                for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
                                    if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
                                        day.className += " disableDay";
                                    }
                                }
                                var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
                                // Check Date against Event Dates
                                for (var n = 0; n < calendar.Model.length; n++) {
                                    var evDate = calendar.Model[n].Date;
                                    var toDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month, (i + 1));
                                    if (evDate.getTime() == toDate.getTime()) {
                                        number.className += " eventday";
                                        var title = document.createElement('span');
                                        title.className += "cld-title";
                                        if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link == 'function' || calendar.Options.EventClick) {
                                            var a = document.createElement('a');
                                            a.setAttribute('href', '#');
                                            a.innerHTML += calendar.Model[n].Title;
                                            if (calendar.Options.EventClick) {
                                                var z = calendar.Model[n].Link;
                                                if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link != 'string') {
                                                    a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                                                    if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                                                        day.className += " clickable";
                                                        day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                                                    if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                                                        day.className += " clickable";
                                                        day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
                                                if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                                                    day.className += " clickable";
                                                    day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            title.appendChild(a);
                                        } else {
                                            title.innerHTML += '<a href="' + calendar.Model[n].Link + '">' + calendar.Model[n].Title + '</a>';
                                        }
                                        number.innerHTML += title.innerHTML + "<br /><br />";
                                        //var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
                                        //number.appendChild(linebreak);
                                    }
                                }
                                day.appendChild(number);
                                // If Today..
                                if ((i + 1) == calendar.Today.getDate() && calendar.Selected.Month == calendar.Today.Month && calendar.Selected.Year == calendar.Today.Year) {
                                    day.className += " today";
                                }
                                days.appendChild(day);
                            }
                            // Next Month's Days
                            // Always same amount of days in calander
                            var extraDays = 13;
                            if (days.children.length > 35) {
                                extraDays = 6;
                            } else if (days.children.length < 29) {
                                extraDays = 20;
                            }

                            for (var i = 0; i < (extraDays - calendar.Selected.LastDay); i++) {
                                var day = document.createElement('li');
                                day.className += "cld-day nextMonth";
                                //Disabled Days
                                var d = (i + calendar.Selected.LastDay + 1) % 7;
                                for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
                                    if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
                                        day.className += " disableDay";
                                    }
                                }

                                var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
                                day.appendChild(number);

                                days.appendChild(day);
                            }
                            mainSection.appendChild(days);
                        }
                        if (calendar.Options.Color) {
                            mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-main{color:' + calendar.Options.Color + ';}</style>';
                        }
                        if (calendar.Options.LinkColor) {
                            mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-title a{color:' + calendar.Options.LinkColor + ';}</style>';
                        }
                        element.appendChild(mainSection);

                        if (calendar.Options.NavShow && calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
                            AddSidebar();
                        }
                        if (calendar.Options.DateTimeShow) {
                            AddDateTime();
                        }
                        AddLabels();
                        AddDays();
                    }

                    function newCalendar(el, data, settings) {
                        var obj = new Calendar(data, settings);
                        createCalendar(obj, el);
                    }
                    // CALENDAR CODE ENDS

                    // Instance of calendar, populates events
                    var events = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < objCampaign.length; i++) {
                        var year = new Date(objCampaign[i].StartDate).getFullYear();
                        var month = new Date(objCampaign[i].StartDate).getMonth();
                        var day = new Date(objCampaign[i].StartDate).getDay();
                        events.push({
                            Date: new Date(year, month, day),
                            Title: objCampaign[i].Name,
                            Link: "https://www.tfaforms.com/4672897?campaignID=" + objCampaign[i].Id
                        });
                    };

                    console.log("EVENTS OBJ\n")
                    console.log(events);
                    var settings = {};
                    var element = document.getElementById('dcCal');

                    newCalendar(element, events, settings);

                } else {
                    console.log("Didn't set the campaigns");
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    }, {
        handleClick: function(component, event, helper) {
            var buttonPressed = event.getSource().getLocalId();
            console.log(buttonPressed);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Use Helper instead of controller . I think with helper it is easy to call another function with this as the variable .

Comment: +1 for Mohith’s comment. Complex logic should be broken down into multiple functions and using a helper allows that. Otherwise seeing errors is made extra hard.

Answer (score 6):

To make this extra clear - the keyword `this` is not available in your controller and the only reason that your local `this` seemingly works is that it is inside the callback for your action.

This callback does have a `this` defined, but it's local to the callback and has no knowledge of the wider controller context.

So, as the commenters say, move most of this code into your helper class, where `this` is defined.

Also, if you are going to call another helper method using `this`, make sure you have the right one.

To preserve `this` and make sure it refers to the wider helper context, save a reference to `this` like so:

```
//helper function:
getCampaignData: function(component) {

    var self = this;
    var action = component.get("c.getCampaigns");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        //validate data, save data, then call self method...
        component.set("v.campaigns", response.getReturnValue());
        self.buildCalendar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Caspar's answer, also note that your controller wasn't correct:

```
}, {
    handleClick: function(component, event, helper) {
        var buttonPressed = event.getSource().getLocalId();
        console.log(buttonPressed);
    }
}
```

This means that handleClick is in a separate object that won't be called correctly. From the last function, the correct method is add a comma and proceed immediately to the next, just like a normal JavaScript object:

```
({
  doInit: function(...) {
    ...
  },
  handleClick: function(...) {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: I have to comment that it is a real bad practice to have a  method is so big and indented (more than 300 lines of code) - it is very hard to look at it, and maintain and would be probably very buggy - you should refactor it and it would be much more easy to maintain

Comment: @ItaiShmida I concur, most of my methods are some odd 20-40 lines, after which I start breaking them up to keep it legible, though there are a few times I'll break my own rule, but only if it's not deeply indented and/or complicated.

Comment: yep - I try to do the same in my code, but here in stackexchange when I see a method this big, usually I don't even try to inspect it as it is too hard to understand and find a problem

Comment: @ItaiShmida Yeah, I try to limit myself to about 10-20 minutes per question, unless they're particularly intriguing (esp. "hacks", "performance", and "optimization"). In this case, I noticed something immediately odd and wrote an answer based on that. I suspect there may be other problems, but they have to start somewhere.